# Updating foreign key on soft delete

Tags: c#, sql, foreign-keys

I have 2 rows in my database.
`Category` and `Movie`.

When I'm soft deleting `Movie`, I want to remove the FK reference to `Category`.

I have a delete method that looks like this:

```
        public override async Task DeleteAsync(long id, bool permanent = false)
        {
            await DbFactory.ExecAsync(async (db) =>
            {
                if (permanent)
                {

                    await db.DeleteAsync<Movie>(x => x.Id == id);
                }
                else
                {
                    await db.UpdateAsync<Movie>(new { Deleted = true, CategoryId = 0 }, x => x.Id == id);
                }
            });
        }
```

But it throws an FK exception when I'm trying to update the `CategoryId`

How can I do this?
I want to be able to soft delete a `Movie`, and then only if the category doesn't have any references be able to remove the category.

Answer (score 0):

Does an entry with `CategoryId` = 0 exist? It probably doesn't, which is why you're getting an error. You have two approaches here:

1. Create a dummy "deleted" category, with Id = 0 (I personally prefer -1 for those things), update to it when softly deleting
2. Set `CategoryId` to `NULL`, if the field allows `NULLs`. This means there's no relation to the category for this record.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, these would be the steps

1. Check whether there are `Any` movies with the same category id, but with different id than the movie to be removed
2. If so, then remove only the movie
3. If not, then remove the Category and cascade (if not possible, then remove the movie first and then the category)

There is also a concurrency problem to handle. What if there are two movies of a category and they are removed at the same time? That could result in an issue that the movies are removed in different threads and both threads check whether there are any other movies and for each movie the other movie is found before it is removed. To cope with this situation, I propose to create a remove movie queue of some kind and when a movie is to be removed, it would enter the queue. This sequential manner of removing movies would fix the concurrency problem.